# Try catch never enters catch block

Tags: sql, try-catch

The problem with the code below is that I never see my `catch` code execute. If my id doesn't exist, it shows a empty datagrid. What goes wrong?

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        SqlConnectie vandaag = new SqlConnectie();
        vandaag.Connection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID, VERSIE, SB, NAAM, M_DATUM, V_DATUM from RE1 where ID=" + tbRecept.Text, SqlConnectie.conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dgvTemp.DataSource = dt;
        SqlConnectie.conn.Close();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ID doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: receiving no result from a sql query is not an error, try catch is used to catch errors being thrown

Comment: You didn't define, what you want to catch. For example: `catch (Exception e)`

But that doesn't cause your "issue". See the answer from Tim

Comment: @JeremyC. what should i use then ?

Comment: what Tim Schmelter said in his answer, just don't use try catch at all in this case, or maybe just leave it in there and make the messagebox show the errorcode (just in case something goes wrong in the future, like database being unavailable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you expect an exception if no row is returned from database? It is perfectly valid to get an empty resultset, the dataadapter will return an empty `DataTable`.

You could check it:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dgvTemp.DataSource = dt;
if(dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("ID doesn't exist");
```